# Fui suspenso nas filas de análise, seria um possível erro da revisão?

Tags: suporte, fechamento, filas-de-análise

Estou recebendo este aviso:

> Review privileges suspended

Só que quando clico no link tem esta mensagem:

> Tivemos um problema nesta revisão:
>
> ```
> /review/first-questions/385363
> ```
>
> A pergunta é completamente fora do escopo do site, ao revisar é
> importante atenção ao motivo correto.

Esta é a justificativa que é exibida para mim. Só que ao entrar [nesta postagem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/551776/112052), ela está fechada.

Verificando o [histórico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/551776/timeline) posso ver que eu sinalizei corretamente:

> 6 horas atrás     histórico   fechada     Danizavtz
> Não é adequada para este site

E mesmo assim recebi uma suspensão. Poderiam informar o real motivo de perder acesso às filas?

Comment: Complementando, uma mensagem melhor para o caso citado seria algo como "*Sua pergunta é fora do escopo, talvez se encaixe melhor no [su] ou [ubuntu.se] (não deixe de ler a Central de Ajuda desses sites antes de postar, para adequar a pergunta ao que é esperado em cada site)*" - Sugiro ver também [**aqui**](/q/707/112052), tem comentários prontos pra várias situações, basta copiar e ajustar (lembrando que na fila dá pra colocar um comentário customizado). Para perguntas que pertencem a outro site, por exemplo, tem [aqui](/a/8449/112052)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Revisando o histórico, até aqui estava tudo ok:

> Não é adequada para este site → Essa pergunta não parece ser sobre programação, dentro do escopo definido na central de ajuda.

O problema desta revisão é que foi usada a opção de dar um feedback para o usuário (através das mensagens "enlatadas" do sistema). É desejável sempre que possível esse passo a mais, porém quando usado, é importante que seja a orientação correta para o caso.

Infelizmente, no caso específico foi escolhida esta mensagem:

> Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

que orienta o usuário a melhorar a postagem. Ocorre que no caso de postagens totalmente fora do escopo do site não há o que ser melhorado, então a orientação acaba atrapalhando em vez de ajudar.

A mensagem escolhida é automaticamente postada pelo bot Comunidade, e no caso, por não ser adequada, foi removida por um dos moderadores.

O prazo da suspensão é de poucos dias, é basicamente um pequeno intervalo até por segurança, para dar tempo de esclarecer a situação, e não tem nenhum desdobramento com outras atividades do site, todos os seus outros privilégios e pontos permanecem intactos.

Diferente seria se fosse caracterizado vandalismo ou má fé, mas nesse caso com certeza você já teria recebido um aviso particular nesse sentido :D - aqui como fica evidente que foi um equívoco, passado o prazo seu acesso às filas é reestabelecido normalmente.

Lembrando ainda que usualmente não é considerada apenas a postagem específica, sempre que possível avaliamos o "conjunto da obra".